# Calculate percentages between columns in hive table

Tags: hive

I have a hive table with three columns; id, num1, num2

```
**id  num1  num2**
1   23    34
2   1     0
3   5    2
4   6    7
```

1. I need the count of total ids whose percentage change between num1 and num2 is more than 20%
   i.e. Absolute((num1 - num2)/num2) >= .20
2. I also need to handle zeros, because any of them may be zero, which may lead to NAN

So the output of the above data will be:
[2,3] because id 2 and 3 has num1 num2 difference more than 20%

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select sum(mycount)
  from
      (select sum(case when abs((num1 - num2)/num2) >= .2 
            and num2 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as mycount
            , id
      from mytable
      group by id
      ) t
   ;
```